# Wordpress Blnak page only at times

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have Wordpress site that i did not develop and the problem is that the main page returns a blank page at times, sometimes i reload the page and the error goes away but returns in the next reload of the page ,this is not happening with any other of the pages in the website, there was to my knowledge a codeguard restore at march 07 and since then this has been happening.

After investigating trough the web i came to find that my problem is descibed as White Screen of Death.

I have tried incrementing the memory limit in wordpress but it did not seem to work, i also tried to activate the debug mode for wordpress, but when i see the blank page i can't see any errors displayed.

The main page of the site is: https://biotempak.com/
Any other page is working fine: https://biotempak.com/eventos/

The php error log displays this error multiple times:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
```

Where else can i start debugging?

Or what steps can i follow to solve this problem?

EDIT: I solved it by deactivationg all the plugins on the page, and then reactivating them one by one untill i found out wich one was the one causing the problem.
Now the page loads faster and presents no errors.

Comment: Sounds like 2 issues, 1st being the cache is broken and that's why its intermittent, your find errors for that in the error log (could be write permissions), I say cache because the site is awfully slow, 2nd is a wrong php.ini setting.

Comment: How can i fix the cache issue?